# El tema THE7 para wordpress no me deja visualizar vectores

Tags: web, desarrollo

Estoy trabajando con el theme THE7 para crear webs, y el tema no me muestra los vectores, ¿cómo puedo modificar los datos del theme para que muestre los vectores? Muchas gracias